Fetch all product details with vertext AI retail search
I am using vertex AI retail search from GCP for product search. Following is the code with python SDK. But it returns only product id and name. I want to fetch title, description and other fields as well.
 # Initialize request argument(s)
request = retail_v2alpha.SearchRequest(
    placement="projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/placements/default_search",
    query="writing lesson",
    visitor_id="test_visitor",
    
)
logging.debug("Request: {}".format(request))
# Make the request
page_result = client.search(request=request)
print(page_result)
# Handle the response
for response in page_result:
    print(response)

The response:
    id: "32"
product {
  name: "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/32"
}

I searched for documentation but nothing is clarified on how to do that and i am stuck on it.
Update:
In documentation it is mentioned that it can guarantee only Product.name to be populated: https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/SearchResponse#searchresult
I am looking to find a way to return more product details like title, description, price, etc.

Hi @Ruchit Rami, Have a look at this vertex AI retail search documentation and let me know if this helped you or not ?

@DhirajSingh I have followed the interective cloudshell tutorial as well, in that as well it returns these values with no mention on how to get full product details with it. Do we need to make different call for each product with it?

@DhirajSingh In documentation it is mentioned that it can guarantee only Product.name to be populated: https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/SearchResponse#searchresult
I am looking to find a way to return more product details like title, description, price, etc.

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Got it resolved, i had to mark relevant fields as retrievable.
